# PHP array value to key

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
params {
  [0] => {
    name  => "xxx"
    value => "yyy"
  } 
  [1] => {
    name  => "uuu"
    value => "vvv"
  }
}
```

and I want to achieve this:

```
params {
  [0] => {
    xxx => "yyy"
  }
  [1] => {
    uuu => "vvv" 
  }
}
```

I can do it this way:

```
foreach ($params as &$param) {
  $param[$param['name']] = $param['value'];
  unset($param['name']);
  unset($param['value']);
  unset($param);
}
```

But I am wondering if this could be done on more elegant way?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ may be more appropriate -- elegance is extremely subjective

Comment: If you're looking for a built in way to accomplish this, there isn't one. You're code is short, accomplishes the task and is readable. I would use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This calls for an [array mapping](http://php.net/array_map) of values:

```
$params = array_map(function ($i) { return [$i['name'] => $i['value']]; }, $params);
```

Comment: hahaha, while being short it dosn't look very *elegant* `:-p`

Comment: That's in the eye of the beholder. A *mapping* is a defined action, and all you need to know is that 1) this is a mapping, 2) what the callback returns. Then it's very precise and readable. Too bad PHP's verbose syntax makes it somewhat ungainly.

Comment: E.g. in Javascript this would be `params = params.map(i => ({ [i.name]: i.value }))`. It hardly gets any more concise than this, and the concept translates to most other languages.

Comment: Yes, I was making the point that OP was asking for *elegance* and NOT for the smallest possible codeblock. I believe it to be a poor question and this is only a subjectively beautiful answer `:-p`

Comment: Well, I consider references and superfluous variables *inelegant*. IMO this is about as elegant as it gets in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_map` to reiterate the array.

```
$params = [
  [
    'name'  => "xxx",
    'value' => "yyy"
  ],
  [
    'name'  => "uuu",
    'value' => "vvv"
  ]
];

$params = array_map(function($o){
    return [ $o['name'] => $o['value'] ];
}, $params);


echo "<pre>";
print_r( $params );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [xxx] => yyy
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uuu] => vvv
        )

)
```

Doc: [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Comment: Just curious, what is the difference with the answer of @deceze?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I didn't realize that someone already answered this approach. Until just now. Haha

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
foreach ($params as $key => $sub_array) {

    // unset original array data
    unset($params[$key]);

    // construct the new values
    $params[$key][$sub_array['name']] = $sub_array['value'];
}
```

EDIT:

Another approach more elegant is the following :

```
foreach($params as $k=>$s){
    $params[$k]=array($s['name']=>$s['value']);
}
```

Comment: why, what does this do? explain your answer

Comment: It simply put the `name` value in the key of parent array as you want. And unset the current `name` and `value` values. That's what you want. You only forgot to use $key in foreach to help you construct the array.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit shorter. By not using `foreach` you can directly replace the elements.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count ($params); $i++)
    $params[$i] = array ($params[$i]['name'] => $params[$i]['value']);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your current code a little bit more elegant, you could pass multiple arguments to [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)

```
foreach ($params as &$param) {
    $param[$param['name']] = $param['value'];
    unset($param['name'], $param['value'], $param);
}
```

Comment: @Martin You don't have to do it to be able to use the new key, but as the OP wanst to remove the old keys and values in the example you could use it.

Comment: Yes that's a fair point. I had missed that; I was looking at it purely as a case of tidying up the `foreach` system.

Comment: No it's not, if you don't unset the values you will have three items in each subarray. But if you build a new array, then yes.

Answer (score -3):

Please try this:

```
foreach ($params as $k => $v)
{
    $nary[$v[name]] = $v[value];
}

$params = $nary;
```

Comment: this won't work without quotes around `name` and `value`. Also OP already says they can do it this way and want something more elegant

Comment: @ThisGuy Depressingly `"$v[name]"` *will* work just fine and `$v[value]` will in fact work for the time being (albeit generating a notice)…

Comment: @deceze ah I edited question for easier reading and forgot no one else can see it XD agreed that it is depressing it still works how it is